# How to get Type from TypeInfo in WinRT?

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-8, windows-runtime

I want to register all my view models for serialization, by convention.

However the following code will not compile because the var `viewmodel` in the foreach loop is of type `TypeInfo`:

```
protected override void OnRegisterKnownTypesForSerialization()
{
    var viewModels = this.GetType().GetTypeInfo().Assembly.DefinedTypes
            .Where(t => _viewModelNameRegex.IsMatch(t.FullName))
            .ToList();

    foreach (var viewmodel in viewModels)
    {
        SessionStateService.RegisterKnownType(viewmodel);
    }
}
```

Apparently `TypeInfo` does not inherit from `Type`:

```
public abstract class TypeInfo : MemberInfo, IReflectableType
```

Unlike the [full featured version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.typeinfo.aspx), which does inherit from `Type`.

So how can I get to `Type` from a WinRT `TypeInfo`?

Comment: It does according to MSDN?..

Comment: `viewmodel.AsType()` ??

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's for the non portable library.

Comment: @sa_ddam213 That's actually correct.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`TypeInfo` inherits from `Type` in the standard .NET library, but in the portable library it is declared as:

```
public abstract class TypeInfo : MemberInfo, IReflectableType
```

The function `AsType()` returns the closest thing to the traditional `Type`

```
public virtual Type AsType()
```

Which returns Type weakly related to the `TypeInfo` above

```
public abstract class Type
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped with a related problem +1